# How to set restriction list to hide everything including comments and activities?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

If you put someone to restriction list, this user doesn't see your comments on your wall. That's one of the expected behaviors. But if you comment an entry in a page or write into the wall of a friend, this user still sees these entries. I want him to not see anything. I can't find any possibility to do that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment on a page then that is public (except for any geographic or age restrictions set by the page admin) and even non-friends can see it.  If you post on your wall/timeline then you control who can see it; if you post to Public then even those on your Restricted list will see it.  If you write on another person's wall/timeline then they control who can see that; the best you could do is to ask the other person if they wouldn't mind restricting those to Friends only (or if the person you are restricting is also their friend and they are not making the posts Public then you could ask them to instead exclude that person).

If you add someone to the Restricted list they will still see be able to see anything that is Public.  It is a way to be Facebook friends with someone without actually allowing them to see anything more than they would be able to see if they were not friends.

If you want them to see even less than what a non-friend can see then block them instead.  From their profile click on the gear and then Report/Block... and choose the Block option.  In that case you will no longer be friends with the person and they will no longer be able to see or like or comment on any posts or comments of yours on pages or the walls of other people, even if they are public, using their account.  In fact they will not be able to view your profile at all and you will not be able to view theirs.

Of course, if the posts are public then they would be able to see them using another account.

It sounds like you may not mind if they can see Public posts, but you just don't want those sent to their News Feed automatically.  However they control which information they want to see in their News Feed, out of the information that they are able to see.  By default, most posts and comments from friends to a page or wall that are visible to the person will appear in their News Feed, although they have the option to not show posts or Comments and Likes from you if they choose.  Even if they only sent you a friend request and you have ignored it, they will still see Public posts by you in their News Feed unless they turn them off.  By default these Public posts can also be seen by going to your profile.  If they are public then they will be difficult to hide.

Comment: Ok, that means it is not possible to keep him as Facebook friend without blocking him and hide "public" messages from him at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Blocking is the only way you can truly not let someone see your comments.

I deleted my account and started a new one because I did not want to "block" any friends.

I selected a few dear friends and made a comment on a friend's thread. Others who I thought could no longer see and reply to my comments did and were able. Ugh. So, yes you might as well block!

I did restrict my settings to only friends in my new account, but it does not apply once you comment on your friend's post. Their friends can see your comment which might be someone you are trying to avoid.